# How can I create a shortcut to switch to a specific keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, language

See I installed some chinese input methods, and some of them have already shortcuts, I'd like to add a shortcut for the one I use mainly so I can come back from chinese quickly without grabbing the mouse.
I inspected the pref pane for keyboard shortcuts but couldn't find out how.

PS: Mine is ArgenPinYin, a customized keyboard layout

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that the shortcuts only appear when you're using Chinese input methods. They don't appear otherwise per [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3560) from Apple's knowledgebase.

I can't find any way around this limitation. However, there is a built-in keyboard shortcut for switching between keyboard layouts, if not for switching to a specific keyboard layout. You can find this shortcut in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard & Text Input:

[image]